# How to Implement Interstitial Admob on RecycleView

Tags: android, admob

Actually i am looking to implement interstitial Admob on RecycleView so that when an image from list is selected it show an Interstitial ad before moving to next activity?? How to define InterstitialAd on Adapter Class?
Any Solution??

```
class imageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    ImageView images;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    Context mtcx;

    ArrayList<Images> img=new ArrayList<Images>();
    public imageViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView,Context mctx,ArrayList<Images> img ) {
        super(itemView);
        this.mtcx=mctx;
        this.img=img;
        images=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
       MobileAds.initialize(mctx, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(mctx);

        interstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");

        interstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                intent();
            }
        });         
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- Create an interstitial ad:

```
 MobileAds.initialize(context, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
            final InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(context);
            mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

2- add Ad events for moving to next activity after close ad:

```
mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdClosed() {
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, NextActivity.class));
                }
            });
```

3- set On Click Listener for show Interstitial Ad after image click:

```
images.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()){
                        mInterstitialAd.show();
                    }else{
                        context.startActivity(new Intent(context, NextActivity.class));
                    }
                }
            });
```

finally your code will be like:

```
class imageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
    ImageView images;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    Context mtcx;

    ArrayList<Images> img=new ArrayList<Images>();
    public imageViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView,Context mctx,ArrayList<Images> img ) {
        super(itemView);
        this.mtcx=mctx;
        this.img=img;
        images = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        MobileAds.initialize(context, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
        final InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(context);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                context.startActivity(new Intent(context, NextActivity.class));
            }
        });
        images.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()){
                    mInterstitialAd.show();
                }else{
                    context.startActivity(new Intent(context, NextActivity.class));
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

hope this help you

Comment: this was answer for your question, but this is not a good way to do it, you have to load ad outside of the adapter, in this case load ad for every item an the recyclerleview

Answer (score 0):

add `intertitialAd.load()` to the bottom of the code above then set the onClickListener like this below all of that:

```
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        if (interstitialAd.isLoaded){
            interstitialAd.show();
           }

        }
    });
```